# Do different eigenstates of total angular momentum have necessarily different energies?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure

Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian of a specific atom and $J$ the total angular momentum. Since $H$ and $J$ commute, they have common eigenstate.
So we can label the atomic states by their energy and total angular momentum $\phi_E^J$.
My question is, suppose we have a state $\phi_E^J$ and another state $\phi_{E'}^{J'}$,  do we have necessarily that $E\neq E'$, that is, do states with different total angular momentum have necessarily different energies?

Comment: You might have heard of hydrogen atom...

Comment: I  mean atoms different from hydrogen

Comment: Given a fixed momentum of inertia, the rotational kinetic energy of a system is monotonically related to the the magnitude of the angular momentum. Therefore, if the system has different angular momentum, it has different energy.

Comment: The magnitude of the angular momentum is  $J=\hbar\sqrt{j(j+1}$ and energy is momentum squared divided by twice the mass (or moment of inertia for rotation) then energy is $J^2/(2I) $ or $\hbar^2 j(j+1)/2I$ so depends on $J$, so different $J$ different energy. This is just the expression for particle on a sphere or rigid rotor.

Comment: well we could have accidentally symmetry

Comment: Accidental energy would only be the case if an external force acted (then it would only be approx the same, not identical), and symmetry is not accidental, because any symmetry would have to be taken into account in any proper calculation.